# Dynamic wrapping according to field:title

Tags: html, css, typo3, typoscript

Edit:
Before you start, please consider that in my original post, the condition i used for illustrating the problem was confusing. I marked it now with ###. This was just meant for showing that i needed an if condition like solution. However, an if condition with brackets [] doesn't work at that point in typoscript. See the solutions down below, which uses override.if. This works perfectly fine!

In a tmenu, created with typoscript, i want to wrap the items differently, according to the title of the pages they belong to. I use Foundation for the width of the elements and therefor the classe large-4. Now the basic wrapping (wrapitemandsub) is no problem, however there is one page with a longer title and i'd need to use the class large-8. In the following code I wrote a condition with an invalid expression, just to demonstrate you how it should behave.

This is the script for the navigation:

```
lib.content_menu = COA
lib.content_menu {

  1 = HMENU
  1 {
    entryLevel = 0
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      expAll = 1
      NO {
        ### [current pagetitle == somevalue]
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="columns small-8 large-8 active">|</li>wrap
        ### [ELSE]
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="columns small-4 large-4">|</li>
        ### [END]
      }
      ACT = 1
      ACT {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="columns small-4 large-4 active">|</li>
      }
      CUR = 1
      CUR < .ACT
      IFSUB = 1
      IFSUB {
        ATagParams = onclick='return false;'
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="columns small-4 large-4">|</li>
      }
      ACTIFSUB = 1
      ACTIFSUB {
        ATagParams = onclick='return false;'
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="columns small-4 large-4 active">|</li>
      }
      CURIFSUB = 1
      CURIFSUB < .ACTIFSUB
    }
    2 = TMENU
    2 {
      wrap = <ul class="menu vertical">|</ul>
      NO {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
      }
      CUR = 1
      CUR {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me on this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context you can use .if or .override - find out more about them in TSRef:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/If/Index.html
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#override

Try it like this:

```
wrapItemAndSub = <li class="columns small-4 large-4">|</li>
wrapItemAndSub.override = <li class="columns small-8 large-8 active">|</li>
wrapItemAndSub.override.if.value = titletocheck
wrapItemAndSub.override.if.equals.field = title
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, this was exactly what i was looking for! I'm quite new to typo (in general), so I really appreciate your help! The [field:] condition was just for illustrating my problem :)

Comment: As TS conditions can not be used inside braces I edited the question to avoid confusion with TS conditions. so no hints about TS condition in answer needed.

Comment: I now also wrote a disclaimer on how the condition is to be percieved. I also changed the condition itsself so its clearly just an example for an if like condition, not especially one from typoscript. I hope it's better now :)